# How to subscribe to certain properties event

Tags: c#, events

I have an object that has many properties. Each time a property changes an event is raised. For performance issue, I want in the view model to subscribe to certain properties event without changing the business object.

I know I can check for the property name in the event handler. But I don't want to go this route since it is a complicated business that have too many properties.

For more clarification, lets say I have the Car class with these properties.
I want to listen to the events of property A,D,G and I want to ignore the rest.

Thank you

```
class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public string A {get {...} set {...}}
 public string B {get {...} set {...}}
 public string C {get {...} set {...}}
 public string D {get {...} set {...}}
 public int E {get {...} set {...}}
 public int F {get {...} set {...}}
 public int G {get {...} set {...}}

 ...
}
```

Comment: one way to source binding?

Comment: First: what "performance issue"? Property-change notification is rarely implicated in performance bottlenecks; why do you think that's a problem in your case, and why do you think that changing the subscription model will fix it? Second, it sounds like you want to restrict event subscription to an event that is directly tied to each individual property, rather than a general `PropertyChanged` event. But if your business object doesn't have these events and you're not willing to change the business object, what do you expect any of us would be able to do to help?

Comment: Third, without a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your question, it's impossible to know what the best approach in your case would be, even if the rest of the question were clear enough (which it's not).

Comment: @Peter Duniho It becomes an issue when the handler try to do a lot of different things each time a property is changed. I know I can restricted to certain properties by checking the property Name but I don't want to each the same event event for all properties is raised to reach out to the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the event handler to only handle one property then only have it handle one property. You can subscribe to the property changed event multiple times

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly Car _car;
    public Example(Car car)
    {
        _car = car;
        _car.PropertyChanged += HandleA;
        _car.PropertyChanged += HandleD;
        _car.PropertyChanged += HandleG;
    }

    private void HandleA(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "A" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.PropertyName))
        {
            //Do logic for A
        }
    }

    private void HandleD(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "D" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.PropertyName))
        {
            //Do logic for D
        }
    }

    private void HandleG(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "G" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.PropertyName))
        {
            //Do logic for G
        }
    }
}
```

The `IsNullOrEmpty` checks are because [a null or empty property name means all properties where updated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into the issue. My issue, would be that  private void HandleA would be called if any if the properties are changed. I know it would not execute unless the property Name is A.

Comment: Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` what you want is impossible, you would need a custom event per property. The overhead of checking the event and seeing that it is not one you care about will be minimal. Someone somewhere needs to make the check. The best you can do is "hide" the check behind some other API like the [PropertyChangedEventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)